# Windows instances on spot

Tags: amazon-ec2

Here is my json file

```
# cat s6.json
    {
      "ImageId": "ami-0b33d91d",
      "InstanceType": "i2.xlarge",
      "KeyName": "xxx"
}
```

And I can use this command...

```
# aws ec2 request-spot-instances --spot-price "1.03" --instance-count 1 --type "one-time" --launch-specification file://s6.json
```

The above command works as expected. But if I change the Image ID to windows **ami-ab33d3bd** I get this error...

> An error occurred (InvalidInput) when calling the RequestSpotInstances
>   operation: Unsupported product.

I can however request a regular on-demand instance without any problem. So this command works...

```
# aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-ab33d3bd --count 1 --instance-type i2.xlarge --key-name xxx
```

Does it mean that Windows instances are not available on spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From EC2-Spot [FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#spot-instances):

> Q. Which operating systems are available as Spot instances?
>
> Linux/UNIX and Windows Server are available. Windows Server with SQL
> Server is not currently available.

The AMI **ami-ab33d3bd** is a Windows Server 2008 with SQL Enterprise which is not supported for Spot.

Comment: Can you provide the link to that FAQ page? I am asking this because official page mentions that spot instances are available. (For lower prices use spot) https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00YQAUZI2